# Access data from two tables from parse with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have two tables in parse. The first one is "user" and the second one is "cars". User table may contain user data eg. name,email,bio,photo etc. The car table may include columns user, carowned , carphoto , carname etc. There can be multiple cars owned by a person.

Now I need to fetch users data, along with the cars he owns. One way to do is I add a pointer in cars table, that points to the user. I then query the cars table along with the pointer. I get the desired results. But when there is no car owned by a user, I may need his personal data form the users table.

So, I need to query users table, that may include all the cars owned by the user.

So far I used the following code:

```
 let Query = PFQuery(className: "car")
    Query.whereKey("user", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser())!)
    Query.includeKey("user")

    Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let user = results?.first!["user"] as? PFUser
        let rideDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()

        rideDataDic["user"] = user!.username
        rideDataDic["userPhoto"] = user!["profilePic"] as? PFFile
        rideDataDic["ratings"] = user!["Ratings"]!
        rideDataDic["noOfRides"] = String(user!["NoOfRides"]!)
        rideDataDic["emailVerified"] = user!["emailVerified"]
        rideDataDic["mobileVerified"] = user!["mobileVerified"]!
        rideDataDic["email"] = user!.email
        rideDataDic["mobileNo"] = user!["mobileNo"]
        rideDataDic["fName"] = user!["FirstName"]!
        rideDataDic["lName"] = user!["LastName"]!
        rideDataDic["DOB"] = user!["DOB"]!
        rideDataDic["gender"] = user!["gender"]
        rideDataDic["bio"] = user!["bio"]

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle

        rideDataDic["memberSince"] = formatter.stringFromDate(user!.createdAt!)

        let calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let ageComponents = calendar.components(.Year,
            fromDate: user!["DOB"] as! NSDate,
            toDate: NSDate(),
            options: [])
        rideDataDic["age"] = String(ageComponents.year)

        let userImageFile = user!["profilePic"] as? PFFile
        userImageFile!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    rideDataDic["userPhoto"] = image
                    self.dataArray.addObject(rideDataDic)
                    self.myAccountTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

        for result  in results! {

            let rideDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()

            rideDataDic["carPhoto"] = result["carPhoto"] as? PFFile
            rideDataDic["carMake"] = result["carMake"]!
            rideDataDic["noOfSeats"] = result["noOfSeats"]
            rideDataDic["carColor"] = result["carColor"]!
            rideDataDic["carComfort"] = result["carComfort"]
            rideDataDic["carType"] = result["carType"]!
            rideDataDic["carModel"] = result["carModel"]!
            rideDataDic["objectId"] = result.objectId

            self.carDataArray.addObject(rideDataDic)

            self.myAccountTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: you already have the current user, if there are no cars you still have the user info...

Comment: Thank you dude, you saved my time. Actually I was new to parse and wasn't aware that parse saves PFUser's all fields locally.